# Is my pet cactus starting to rot?

Tags: indoors, cactus, roots

[image: James' pet cactus Ludwig]I have a mini cactus named Ludwig and last Wednesday I repotted him. His rots look healthy, no signs of bugs. And last time I watered him was days before repotting. He is growing his four stems, but today I found that his base is brownish (see picture) and when I touched it, it's still solid/hard. Is this root rot or just a normal color for a cactus? If it's root rot, please tell me how to fix it. I don't wanna lose Ludwig, he is the only cactus I have now. I live in Indonesia and the weather is really hot here right now.